# Notepad++: how to recover a deleted file?

Tags: notepad++

Notepad++ has a "Keep non existing dialog".
I wrongly clicked on "NO" on this dialog and now want to know if is there any way to reopen the deleted file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Recover it as a normal file, there are tools for that

http://pcsupport.about.com/od/filerecovery/tp/free-file-recovery-programs.htm

You can alternatively use the recovery folder of Notepad++

http://buffernow.com/notepad-plus-crash-recover-your-lost-file/

Comment: It isn't possible. I tried some tools but seems that the disk is rewrited. This is the reason that I am going to get help of NP++

Answer (score 78):

Just before crashing NotePad++ creates a backup file you could find here : %AppData%/Notepad++/backup
This trick saved me so much time and work!
I hope this would work with you too!

Comment: Thanks! NP++ truncated my file completely and I had no backups, but the NP++ backup was still in the specified folder as `AutoLoader.php@2014-08-27_211318`.

Comment: @CPG, "Just before crashing" is wrong. When it crashes, by definition it couldn't do anything. The files are saved because they are saved **periodically** every 7 (settable) seconds.

Comment: Thanks GOD!!!!!! It saved me two days of work. In Windows 7 the path is `%AppData%\Roaming\Notepad++\backup` (AppData folder is in your user's home folder).

Answer (score 19):

> **Did you LOST/DELETED/CRASHED your notepad++ file?**
>   Which you think you Gonna type them all Again :(
>
> **Na, no need & no worries you still have it try this method...** :)
>
> ### ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> 1. **Try run** - by **win+r** (clicking windows button on keyboard and R together)
> 2. **Past this path** -
>      **%AppData%/Notepad++/plugins/config/NppFTP/Cache**
> 3. if method didn't work for you as you already closed the program
>      after the fatal error.
>
>    **Then Instead of pasting this**
>
>    **%AppData%/Notepad++/plugins/config/NppFTP/Cache**
>
>    as suggested above, go a few sub-directories back and one over, to
>
>    **%AppData%/Notepad++/backup**
>
>    **TADA!!** Hopefully a copy of your lost file should be there.Mine was.
>
> ---
>
> ```
>      ----->  **Cheers !! Hopefully this helps others too** <-----
> ```

Answer (score 4):

If notepad wasn't able to create backup file and crashed. At that point it tried to recover files as dump which could be found at following place

> %AppData%\Local\Temp\N++RECOV