# Why Notepad++ doesn't have backups? (Windows 7)

Tags: backup, notepad++

Notepad++ crashed and get my file lost (not only unsaved part - the complete file's lost)

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21712139/notepad-how-to-recover-a-deleted-file) and went to `%AppData%/Notepad++/backup`. But there's not backup for that file.

It looks strange that most recent backup is on 6/27/2015 - and I've been using Notepad++ a lot after that time.

[image]

Very lucky me - the file is in OneDrive (cloud storage) folder, and I got it back from the cloud. Still curious about the backup file of notepad++. Any discussion is appreciated.

---

Update: I checked the setup and it looks the backup is on.
[image]

Is it possible that Notepad++ thought I saved it as a blank file? I think I'm turning on backup on save...

Comment: What is the backup setting? May be its disabled

Comment: Look at Notepad++ menu => **Settings** => **Preferences** => **Backup** and check that the settings there will, in the future, do what you want.

Comment: thanks guys! It look the backup is on... See update please

Comment: Your screen shot show "backup on save" == none. I use "Simple backup".

Comment: If you use the version from Microsoft Store, the location would be something like "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Packages\NightRise.NotepadWrapped_bahp16nyyek9m\LocalCache\Roaming\Notepad++\backup". I almost gave up, when I luckily found this folder when I searched for "Notepad" in my Users folder.