# Notepad++ crashed and overwrote file with empty version

Tags: notepad++

I come with an all-too-familiar tale that really comes down to me not backing up frequently enough and suffering the consequences of that.  Anyway, maybe someone can offer me some help, so here goes ...

I was working on a CSS file in *Notepad++ (6.9.2)*, when the program suddenly crashed. Upon reopening the program, I found that it had emptied my file and saved this empty file, overwriting my original file. So, now I cannot recover my CSS file. I have checked in the *User/AppData/Roaming/Notepad++/backup* folder; however, the lost file is not one of the ones listed there.

There is also a crashdump file that coincides with the time of this crash, but I am not sure whether that could be of any help in recovering the file.

I am hoping that there is some way to recover this file - even if it is a somewhat earlier version of it.  I assume that I'm out of luck here, but thought that I'd ask anyway.

Answer (score 8):

If it's not in [`%AppData%/Notepad++/backup`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24914603/616460) you may be SOL. You could try using a deleted file recovery tool, cross your fingers, and hope some old version of it is buried somewhere, but chances here are slim, and are zero if you never saved your file in the first place.

Since you say you were editing a CSS file, if you also had a page using it open in your browser and haven't closed it yet, it's possible that it's still available there e.g. in the resource panel in Chrome or something. Also if you type `about:cache` into Chrome (or whatever for your favorite browser) you can view the cache, perhaps it is there, although I do not know if browsers make a habit of caching local files.

In the future, presuming you continue to use *Notepad++*, I recommend enabling automatic backups:

1. Settings → Preferences → Backup
2. Check "remember current session", "enable session backups", and enter your favorite settings.

I also recommend using something like git or another version control system to keep your source files in, committing after large changes, so worst case you can restore to a previous commit.

Bummer. Good luck!

Comment: That's what I thought - thank you.  I actually already have those settings selected.  I think the problem comes in, because the program saved the empty file upon crashing.  The only files backed up are the ones that were not saved when it crashed.

Comment: git. Most definitely get comfortable with git. Soon enough, you'll ask yourself how you ever managed to work without it.

Answer (score 3):

Just got this problem. Just go to **AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\backup**. If you are lucky enough, the file would be present there.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above answers, newer versions of NotePad++ will save time and date stamped backups in a subfolder of the file location called nppBackup.